# Why Doesn't Rails Scaffold Include Json Rendering for Edit in Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, controller

This is just out of curiosity, here's a generated controller from running `rails g scaffold Thing`:

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /things
  # GET /things.json
  def index
    @things = Thing.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @things }
    end
  end

  # GET /things/1
  # GET /things/1.json
  def show
    @thing = Thing.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @thing }
    end
  end

  # GET /things/new
  # GET /things/new.json
  def new
    @thing = Thing.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @thing }
    end
  end

  # GET /things/1/edit
  def edit
    @thing = Thing.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /things
  # POST /things.json
  def create
    @thing = Thing.new(params[:thing])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @thing.save
        format.html { redirect_to @thing, notice: 'Thing was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @thing, status: :created, location: @thing }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @thing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /things/1
  # PUT /things/1.json
  def update
    @thing = Thing.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @thing.update_attributes(params[:thing])
        format.html { redirect_to @thing, notice: 'Thing was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @thing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /things/1
  # DELETE /things/1.json
  def destroy
    @thing = Thing.find(params[:id])
    @thing.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to things_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Rails includes a `format` block in every action except for `edit`... Why is this? Theoretically another app pinging the server for json would still want to show whatever is being edited, right?  It's easy enough to just add in, but I am curious why they chose to do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know what you are updating, you can do it via the `show` action.